# $_GET gives always 1

Tags: php, post, get

I am new at get/post methods. I create my own license manager plugin. I have completed 90% of things.

I have plugin.php?license=60f416581f911 link. my plugin checks this URL and gets JSON from there. I want to set license code system into this method.

to make this, in that PHP file, I wrote below code.

```
<?php
if ($_GET["license"] = "60f416581f911" ) {
//these code always work.In other words, if gives always 1 when I change license code
```

I want to work the code if the license code is true but they works always.to test it, I change the license code.

probably, it is related syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be `==`, not `=` like you did.

Comment: you are right. can you thumb up my question?

Comment: We dont normally answer TYPO's like this, we make a simple comment to put the OP on the right track again and then delete the question. Typo's are almost never actually any use to others, whic his the prime function  of SO

Comment: Okay thanks @RiggsFolly, I was not aware of that